# Updating ParametricPlot3D code from Getz and Helmstedt book to use V10.3 features

Tags: graphics, version-10

I purchased a version of *Graphics with Mathematica, Fractals, Julia Sets, Patterns and Natural Forms*, by Chonta Getz and Janet Helmstedt, written in 2004. Really fun book.

I'm looking at the following code.

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  {(9 Cos[θ] - Cos[9 θ]) Cos[t] - 5 t, 
   (9 Sin[θ] - Sin[9 θ]) Cos[t] - 7 t, 
   7 t, 
   RGBColor[0.52 + Abs[t/(2 π)], 0.8 - Abs[t/(2 π)], 0.54]}, 
  {t, -π/2, π/2}, {θ, 0, 2 π},
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  ViewPoint -> {2.870, 1.385, 1.137},
  Axes -> False,
  Boxed -> False,
  Lighting -> False]
```

Now, this was back in the day when `ParametricPlot3D` did not have a `PlotStyle` option. Of course, this code will not work in the latest version of *Mathematica* 10.3.0.0, but I am wondering how I would repair it to get their image, which looks like this:

[image]

I am enjoying their discussion and use of color, so what I am looking for in this question is how to employ their color intent in the latest version of *Mathematica*.

Comment: If you want to experience the old system: ``<<Version5`Graphics` ``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`RGBColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RGBColor.html) is moved to the [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) option

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 {(9 Cos[θ] - Cos[9 θ]) Cos[t] - 5 t,
  (9 Sin[θ] - Sin[9 θ]) Cos[t] - 7 t, 7 t},
 {t, -π/2, π/2}, {θ, 0, 2 π},
 ColorFunction -> (
   RGBColor[0.52 + Abs[#4/(2 π)],
     0.8 - Abs[#4/(2 π)], 0.54] &),
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 ViewPoint -> {2.870, 1.385, 1.137},
 Axes -> False,
 Boxed -> False,
 Background -> ColorData["CoffeeTones"][.9]]
```

[image]

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that #1, #2, and #3 refer to x, y, and z, and since the first parameter is t, that's #4? And #5 would correspond with $\theta$?

Comment: @David - yes you are correct. This is covered in the documentation for [ColorFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html).

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `RGBColor` stuff in there, and fixing the `Lighting` option, made it work:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{
  (9 Cos[\[Theta]] - Cos[9 \[Theta]]) Cos[t] - 5 t,
  (9 Sin[\[Theta]] - Sin[9 \[Theta]]) Cos[t] - 7 t,
  7 t},
 {t, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Axes -> False,
 Boxed -> False,
 PlotPoints -> 50, ViewPoint -> {2.870, 1.385, 1.137}, 
 Lighting -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]